# Java Scanner Delimeter semicolon and newline

Tags: java

I would like to tell my scanner to read one line as anything before ;**CR** (semicolon followed by carriage return)

```
scan.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("(;\\n)"));
```

I tried the above and get no such element during `.next()`.

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: **CR** is `\r`, not `\n`, which is **LF**. See [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: I see no reason for closing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern `"\\n"` will match **LF** - Line Feed character. *CR* is Carriage Return, it's a different character and it should be written as `"\\r"`